# What is the name of the small containers of half & half, etc.?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, synonyms

Does anyone know what the word/name for the small plastic cup things that contain liquids (like half and half for coffee) is?

Right now I’m using *sachet* because a coworker started to do so, but I’ve never heard them being called that (looked it up and apparently it's legit).

I’ve thought of *packets* but I feel like there might be a proper word for it. Also, what do people call it in everyday usage? I don’t drink coffee so I’ve never really had to think about it.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a *sachet*; that's a bag or wrapper, as in the illustration in the *Wikipedia* [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sachet_(package)).

Comment: @tchrist yeah the little cuppy thingies. The ones I open just for fun sometimes haha

Comment: @tchrist - love that you think like me!

Comment: I wouldn't call any of these things a _sachet_ - although apparently that _is_ a [usable term](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sachet). I've heard of _creamers_ with the cream, and _packets_ of ketchup, but I'd probably expect some odd looks if I asked for a _sachet of mustard_, for example.

Comment: I vote we call them *cuppy thingies*.

Comment: I would like to call them cuplets, pronounced the same as couplets.

Comment: Very common terms for these packets in the United States are "single-serve cups" and  "mini cups." The packets that contain coffee or cocoa for making a single serving of the beverage with a Keurig machine, however, are called "K-cup pods."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The industry appears to refer to them as both *tubs* and *cups*, often combined with the adjectival phrase *portion control*. Examples:

- http://www.cw-usa.com/coffee-international-delight-hazelnut-creamer-cup.html
- http://www.roundeyesupply.com/Nestle-Coffee-Mate-Regular-Liquid-Creamer-Portion-p/de356761.htm

[image]

Comment: Hmm, in my mind *tubs* would insinuate a larger container, but I'm starting to like *cups*. Thanks, I'll leave this for a little bit so I don't accept too soon!

Comment: Industrial terms often apply independently of scale: [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SydneyHarbourBridgeNutMilsonsPoint.JPG), for example, is a nut and bolt.

Comment: Downvoter: care to leave a constructive suggestion for improving the answer?

Comment: @MetaEd yeah, I guess that does make sense, but the detail I failed to provide was that this is being used in an explanation of a technical detail, so I guess I'm looking for the word that would more readily bring that object I'm describing to mind rather than a technically correct one. Does that make any sense? That's why I think cup is going to be the go-to word here unless you have any more suggestions.

Comment: I wouldn't hesitate to call them cups, tubs, or creamers (suggested by @mr-shiny-and-new in his answer).

Comment: The industry also calls them 'milk pots'. [ [CoffeeeBuyer](http://www.coffeebuyer.co.uk/mall/departmentpage.cfm/thecoffeebuyer/_511768/1/Milk-Pots) ]

Comment: Additionally "cups" is used to refer to the similarly sized single-serve coffee-holders that have proliferated in the last few years, to the extent that the most famous brand talks about "K-cups"

Answer (score 10):

I have heard these things called *creamers*, probably in reference to the non-disposable variety.

> A creamer is a small pitcher or jug designed for holding cream or milk to be served with tea or coffee in the Western tradition. Creamers can be earthenware or porcelain, but also made of silver or other metals; a creamer is an obligatory part of a coffee or tea set, whether in silver or ceramics.
>   [-- from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creamer_%28crockery%29)

Comment: +1 Very interesting! I've never heard of it being used as the *vessel* rather than the contents. However, if you look at the comment I posted on @MetaEd's answer, in my opinion those words bring the object I'm describing to mind rather than *creamer*. Would you agree with that statement? To me, instinctively the word describes the additive.

Comment: +1 Never thought about it before (like many things before SE!) but I guess we do refer to them as creamers in the office.  "Toss me a creamer!"

Comment: +1. I don't think that "creamer" refers to the non-disposable vessel in this case (although that is another sense of the word). I think this is the right answer because those little cups frequently hold "non-dairy creamer" (which is what e.g. CoffeeMate is described as), and "creamer" the word for the liquid leaches into a shorthand for describing the whole little package, which can then contain actual cream, or other substances.

Comment: @quixoto The wikipedia link I posted does call the cream-containing vessel a "creamer". I swear I am not making this up :)

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇: Oh, no doubt, I know you're not; I call those pitchers creamers myself. However, it's my hypothesis that the the little guys are called "creamers" for a different reason: not because they're small versions of the pitchers, but because of what they contain. Just a theory.

Comment: @quixoto Wouldn't the little ones be called creamers both because they are smaller, disposable versions of the big ones, and because they contain cream? Actually, if they _didn't_ contain cream, they wouldn't be smaller versions of the big ones, they'd be something else. Ketchupers, maybe.

Comment: I think I agree with @quixoto: the little cups are called "creamers" via metonymy and/or synecdoche (I always get those two confused), not because they're miniature plastic analogues of a particular part of a tea set. If you put ketchup in a similar container, you'll find yourself asking for "three ketchups, please"; you wouldn't say "three ketchup creamers".

Answer (score 7):

At least [one maker](http://www.internationaldelight.com/CreamerSingles) calls them *singles* – short for single-serving, I presume.

That said, in that case, I'd say *single* refers to the name of the product, not the container.  However, I might call it a *single-sized creamer*, or a *disposable creamer*.

As for a generic name of the container itself, I'm not sure if there's a formal name for a cup that small. In the case where they are filled with cream, flavored cream, or half-and-half, [**creamer cup**](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=creamer%20cup&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&biw=1549&bih=846&wrapid=tlif134928122887610&safe=active&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=1GVsUKmSDuf50gHftYHYCQ#um=1&hl=en&safe=active&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=%22creamer%20cup%22&oq=%22creamer%20cup%22&gs_l=img.3..0i24l2j0i5i24.14040.16445.0.17298.2.2.0.0.0.0.173.318.0j2.2.0...0.0...1c.1.IGVuD0q7gKA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=94fe7cbc009ee6f3&biw=1549&bih=846) could work.  Typing that term into Google images returns several variants:

[image]

However, if a company were to put, say, soy sauce in the same container, I don't think *creamer cup* would be apt for that.

Comment: Insert Fight Club reference here.

Answer (score 4):

Seems it seems as if you are looking for a word that would have people understand what you mean, regardless of whether there is actually a technical word for it, I will say that I have heard them called *mini-tubs* or just miniature tubs.  Since *cup* seems to me generally to imply a handle, *tub* is better in my mind.

> miniature tubs of [creamer]

would therefore be my vote.

Like you, I think of the contents and not the container when I heard *creamer*.

Comment: One brand calls theirs "mini-moos". (For non-natives, "moo" is imitative of a cow's voice.) I think any of "mini", "mini tub"  or "mini - INSERT PRODUCT NAME" is probably a good choice.

Answer (score 2):

Great question.

In most fast food places, such as McDonald’s, Subway, and Burger King, they are called *creams* in casual talk:

- How many creams do you want?
- Can I have three creams, please?

In a coffee shop or café you would ask for *cream to go*. Most coffee and donut places will have both the cream to go and a large quart of half-and-half. If they run out, just ask for *half-and-half* or *cream to go*.

The small container is mainly a cup of cream for travelers.

Comment: "I'd like four creams" falls under metonymy/synecdoche: you're naming the thing for what it contains — if the thing contains something else, the name doesn't transfer. They make ketchup containers these days that greatly resemble a half-and-half container, but you wouldn't say "I'd like 4 ketchup creams"; you'd just stick to "I'd like 4 ketchups". Which is all well and good in everyday usage, but if you're trying to refer to the containers, not the contents thereof, you're stuck with circumlocutions like "those thingies that contain half-and-half".

Answer (score 2):

These are called creamers in restaurants in English Canada, when they are referred to at all (most people would just ask for milk). If you used any of the other terms being bandied about in this thread, e.g. mini tubs, no server would know what you were talking about. No opinion in other contexts, including in French Canada, industrial or other countries, because I have no specific experience.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, one name used for those (in Britain, at least) is "jiggers" (see [Google Images](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=milk%20jiggers&safe=strict&source=lnms&tbm=isch)). The only related definition of jigger I know is as a shot measure for alcoholic drinks.

I can't say it's a term I've heard used, but one company has even branded themselves as [MilkJiggers.com](https://www.milkjiggers.com/).

Comment: As a lifelong resident of south east England I have never heard of this!

Answer (score 0):

In New Zealand there is a 'pottle' which is a circular lidded plastic container of about, oh 300-400 mls capacity.  Fruit salad or berries, and take-away salads are often sold in such containers.

Comment: I think the question is asking about smaller containers of about 10ml or so.

Comment: That's interesting, because the _pottle_ is also a half gallon unit of measure and that's more like 1.9 liter.

Answer (score -3):

According to the wikipedia entry for 'half and half' accessed today (Sep 28, 2017), they are called milkettes.